# WIndows 10 Memory Management - used, free, standby and file cache.... What is going on?

Tags: windows-10, performance, memory-management

I have a W10 system which, while quite old now is not a slouch (Dell Precision T3620 with i7-6700, 32GB RAM, GTX 1060 6GB, 512 GB NVME, 2x512 SSD and 4TB HDD). I use it for work (software & DB development) and fun (streaming, gaming), so it has constantly something resource-intensive on.

Imagine my surprise when i started having some issues with game performance (older games, mostly pre 2015) some months ago, after major updates... Which didn't happen at all previously. By all accounts, every game I run should work at max at Ultra or notch lower) and while working dev system should be rather responsive... and not constantly accessing disk(s)... And it's sometimes struggling a lot.

Imagine my further surprise, when i started looking at Performance Monitor, then deeper still. Performance monitor shows 12GB used (lot of chrome tabs - guilty), but then 18GB standby was somewhat expected only. Looking deeper into that reveals SQL Server. Fine, I do have several databases there. But it's still not explaining sluggishness.

Imagine my biggest surprise when I saw that system automatically allocated 81GB (yes, eighty-one gigabytes) to pagefile, and put it on the HDD (5400RPM spinner with just lots or RAM) of all places...

My question is this: taking into account what I have, what I do and what Windows did, should I keep it that way or should I tweak setup a bit (relocate pagefile to nvme, disable superfetch, turn some services off when unused - like the SQL Server, something else)? I can't remember last time something crashed (WarThunder works like a dream, World of Warships as well, SQL Server is not bad, Visual Studio is also not crashy - though still a slug), but the slowness overall is annoying. Is it possible that leaving it all to Windows yields that stability for the price of performance? If yes, can I tweak it just a bit to make it all faster?

Comment: try configuring"max server memory" for sql server (see for example: https://serverfault.com/questions/990091/ ), limiting pagefile size, and placing it on a faster drive. You should be aware that some older games have horrible performance on newer hardware because they did {magic} that worked for the time but is "too cozy" with the hardware or OS and disrupts OS behavior. One such involves the developer forcing low-level HDD routines to handle "fast" streaming which worked then but introduces ridiculous drive latency on modern hardware.

Comment: @Yorik - thanks for reminding me of that. Duh. Other options tried and discarded, so went for hardware solution and upgraded. All in my answer. But I would not figure it all out without your prompt, so thank you from the bottom of my heart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR** - Problem solved by throwing more money at it. New PC with essentially quadrupled capabilities (128GB RAM, 2TB NVMe Gen4, 4TB NVMe Gen3, 8TB HDD, etc.), clean Windows 11 installation, few days of installing apps and restoring data, extra time to configure for max stability (i.e. NO OC/XPM/etc.) - solved performance issues.

**Long Explanation**

After investigating further the issue has been identified:

Windows was configured to optimize for services and page file was set to be managed by Windows. Since there was the need for a lot of memory (160GB total), for all the services and/or applications running, Windows tried to cope.

I think it is worth highlighting that it coped successfully, from my POV. Yes, system was slow, but not unstable. For all the sluggishness and apps crashing on startup, system was up and running for couple of months. Which means that no data was lost.

Majority of that sluggishness was due to SQL Server running in the background, managing 4 databases. It had to use the spinner because no SSD had enough space available to keep it all in one place.

I set up DBs in SQL Server to auto-close (they were all modified for GDPR restore-from-PROD-backups, so added that to anonymizing scripts). Since all were local, I had no issues with prolonged first-today access time, and I always could go make coffee while waiting for DB to be up again.

This issue however, prompted me to shell out for new PC. Since I could afford it, I splurged for new system with max RAM and more storage space on fast devices, so if this happens again, the performance impact will be - hopefully - minimum. Since upgrade no problems whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Wagnardsoft's [Intelligent standby list cleaner](https://www.wagnardsoft.com/ISLCw) has been helpful in freeing up memory for me, not only in games, but for other memory memory-intensive tasks, such as moving many books to a reader with Calibre, or processing large panoramas.

As for the pagefile, rather than let Windows allocate it automatically, I [set maximum and default to the same amount](https://computerinfobits.com/adjust-page-file-windows-10/), about 1.5 to 2 times RAM. This not only limits usage of slow disk I/O as memory, it also helps prevent fragmentation of that file.